# Direction Cosines of the a line perpendicular to two lines

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

If $\alpha' ,\beta' ,\gamma'$  and $\alpha'' ,\beta'' ,\gamma'' $  are the direction angles of two lines, we have to find $\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma $ such that they are the direction angles of a third line perpendicular to both.

**MY SOLUTION**

I understand there are three equations like this:

1. $\sum \cos \alpha\cdot \cos \alpha ' = 0 $
2. $\sum \cos \alpha\cdot \cos \alpha '' = 0 $
3. $\sum \cos \alpha\cdot \cos \alpha    = 1 $

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \alpha & \cos \beta & \cos \gamma\\
\cos \alpha' & \cos \beta'  & \cos \gamma' \\
\cos \alpha'' & \cos \beta''  & \cos \gamma''
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \alpha\\
\cos \beta\\
\cos\gamma
\end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

By Cramer's rule, I arrive at:
$$\cos \alpha = \frac{\cos \beta'}{\cos \beta' \cos \gamma'' - \cos \beta'' \cos \gamma'}.$$

But the answer given is somewhat different, given as
$$\lambda \cdot \cos \alpha = \cos \beta' \cos \gamma'' - \cos \beta'' \cos \gamma'.$$

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**

The RHS should be $[1, 0, 0]^T$ rather than $[0, 0, 1]^T$ as pointed by Inquest. But my answer eludes me even more.

Comment: Shouldn't your vector be [1 0 0] and not [0 0 1] ?

Comment: Yes it should be, I am sorry. But I just reworked its giving an even weird result, as by Cramers rule it is coming out as zero.

Comment: What is $\lambda$?

Comment: Apparently some indeterminate parameter , $\lambda^{2} = sin^{2} \theta $ where $\theta$ is the angle between the two given lines. THis result is arrived by substitution the solution as espoused in eqn (3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\ca{\cos\alpha}
\def\cb{\cos\beta}
\def\cc{\cos\gamma}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\det{\mathrm{det}\,}
\def\VA{{\bf A}}$Let 
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\ca & \cb & \cc \\
\ca' & \cb' & \cc' \\
\ca'' & \cb'' & \cc''
\end{array}\right).$$
Denote the $i$th row by $\VA_i$ and let $\l = \det A$. 
Then $|\l|$ is the [volume of the parallelepiped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped#Volume) defined by $\VA_1$, $\VA_2$, and $\VA_3$.
Since $\VA_1$ is perpendicular to the other vectors and has unit magnitude, $|\l|$ is the [area of the parallelogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram) defined by the vectors
$\VA_2$ and $\VA_3$.
Therefore, $|\l| = \sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.
*Note in particular that $|\l|$ does not depend on $\alpha$, $\beta$, or $\gamma$.*
This argument could be written to avoid the terminology of vectors, but it would be cumbersome.

By Cramer's rule
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\ca &=& \frac{%
\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \cb & \cc \\
0 & \cb' & \cc' \\
0 & \cb'' & \cc''
\end{array}\right|}{%
\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\ca & \cb & \cc \\
\ca' & \cb' & \cc' \\
\ca'' & \cb'' & \cc''
\end{array}\right|}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
and so 
$$\ca = \frac{1}{\l}(\cb'\cc''-\cb''\cc').$$

Answer (score 1):

In problems like this vector cross product works nicely.
Recall that cross product of two vectors gives a vector perpendicular to both

[image]

You can take

$$a=(\cos \alpha',\cos \beta',\cos \gamma')$$
$$b=(\cos \alpha'',\cos \beta'',\cos \gamma'')$$
$$c=(\lambda\cos \alpha,\lambda\cos \beta,\lambda\cos \gamma)$$
(here $\lambda$ is just some constant dependent on $\theta$)
and then take $$c=a\times b$$
Evaluate the determinant and you get answer immediately.

Also if you have any doubt take a look at wiki page of [Vector cross product.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Comment: yes, I understand that- vector is something I intuitively understand but analhytical methods for me is both slightly abstract than vectors and their methods more cumbersome. Hence I provided for my solution both to show that I worked it out myself but also to show that I want solution on analytical lines. Thanks though. And yes, I do understand how it will look through cross product.